# Issue with KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a small class that implements KeyListener, but even though I implemented all methods, including keyPressed(), and gave them all code to run, nothing happens when I press the enter (return) key.

Here is the class that I made implement KeyListener (the implemented methods are at the bottom):

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
Words word = new Words();
private JLabel rootLabel;
JLabel rootField;
private JLabel defLabel;
JTextField defField;
private JButton ok;
TestListener listener;
private JLabel correctLabel;
private JLabel incorrectLabel;
private int correctCount = 0;
private int incorrectCount = 0;
ActionListener okListener = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (defField.getText().equals("")) {

        } else {

            String root = word.getRoot();
            String def = word.getDef();
            boolean status;
            if (defField.getText().equals(word.getDef())) {
                correctCount++;
                correctLabel.setText("Correct: " + correctCount);
                status = true;
            } else {
                incorrectCount++;
                incorrectLabel.setText("Incorrect: " + incorrectCount);
                status = false;
            }

            defField.setText("");
            word.setRootAndDef();
            rootField.setText(word.getRoot());
            TestEvent event = new TestEvent(ok, root, def, status);
            listener.dataSubmitted(event);

        }

    }

};

public TestPanel() {
    word = new Words();
    rootLabel = new JLabel("Root: ");
    rootField = new JLabel();
    defLabel = new JLabel("Definition: ");
    defField = new JTextField(20);
    ok = new JButton("OK");
    correctLabel = new JLabel("Correct: " + correctCount);
    incorrectLabel = new JLabel("Incorrect: " + incorrectCount);

    ok.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Test"));

    ok.addActionListener(okListener);

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    // First row

    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 0.2;
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);

    add(rootLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

    add(rootField, gc);

    // Next row

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);

    add(defLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

    add(defField, gc);

    // Next row

    gc.weighty = 2;
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

    add(ok, gc);

    // Next row

    gc.weighty = 0.1;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 20);

    add(correctLabel, gc);

    gc.weighty = 0.1;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

    add(incorrectLabel, gc);
}

public void setTestListener(TestListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public int getCorrectCount() {
    return correctCount;
}

public int getIncorrectCount() {
    return incorrectCount;
}

public void setCorrectCount(int correctCount) {
    this.correctCount = correctCount;
}

public void setIncorrectCount(int incorrectCount) {
    this.incorrectCount = incorrectCount;
}

public void setCorrectLabel(String text) {
    correctLabel.setText(text);
}

public void setIncorrectLabel(String text) {
    incorrectLabel.setText(text);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keySource) {

    int key = keySource.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        if (defField.getText().equals("")) {

        } else {

            String root = word.getRoot();
            String def = word.getDef();
            boolean status;
            if (defField.getText().equals(word.getDef())) {
                correctCount++;
                correctLabel.setText("Correct: " + correctCount);
                status = true;
            } else {
                incorrectCount++;
                incorrectLabel.setText("Incorrect: " + incorrectCount);
                status = false;
            }

            defField.setText("");
            word.setRootAndDef();
            rootField.setText(word.getRoot());
            TestEvent event = new TestEvent(ok, root, def, status);
            listener.dataSubmitted(event);

        }
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keySource) {

    int key = keySource.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        if (defField.getText().equals("")) {

        } else {

            String root = word.getRoot();
            String def = word.getDef();
            boolean status;
            if (defField.getText().equals(word.getDef())) {
                correctCount++;
                correctLabel.setText("Correct: " + correctCount);
                status = true;
            } else {
                incorrectCount++;
                incorrectLabel.setText("Incorrect: " + incorrectCount);
                status = false;
            }

            defField.setText("");
            word.setRootAndDef();
            rootField.setText(word.getRoot());
            TestEvent event = new TestEvent(ok, root, def, status);
            listener.dataSubmitted(event);

        }
    }

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keySource) {

    int key = keySource.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        if (defField.getText().equals("")) {

        } else {

            String root = word.getRoot();
            String def = word.getDef();
            boolean status;
            if (defField.getText().equals(word.getDef())) {
                correctCount++;
                correctLabel.setText("Correct: " + correctCount);
                status = true;
            } else {
                incorrectCount++;
                incorrectLabel.setText("Incorrect: " + incorrectCount);
                status = false;
            }

            defField.setText("");
            word.setRootAndDef();
            rootField.setText(word.getRoot());
            TestEvent event = new TestEvent(ok, root, def, status);
            listener.dataSubmitted(event);

        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Just a stupid question, but where is the `addKeyListener(...)` lines of code? After you answer this, we can discuss the finer details of why using a KeyListener with Swing GUI's is usually not recommended, but first things first.

Comment: My first thought is, don't.  Use the `ActionListener` support of the button and text fields instead directly

Comment: Oh, I forgot that, thank you for reminding me, that should fix my problem.

Comment: ..............seriously!

Comment: *"that should fix my problem"* - Umm, not likely.  You need to understand that a `KeyListener` will only generate key events if the component it is registered to has keyboard AND is focusable.  This means that while either the text field or button has focus, your `KeyListener` won't be notified

Comment: I think I forgot to use addKeyListener(), but tell me why it is not recommended to do this.

Comment: I've never done it before, so tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: See previous comment.  In your case though, it's overkill, just use the `ActionListener` support of the button and text field

Comment: Please tell me what focus is and how to fix it so this works

Comment: You're also assuming the [Enter] is the default "action" key, where it isn't on all OS's, on some OS's, you need to use [Space] to trigger a button :P

Comment: Well, actually, the whole point is that I don't know how to make it so that the enter key will generate an event instead of having to click the button.

Comment: *"Please tell me what focus is and how to fix it so this works"* - Use the `ActionListener` support the buttons and text fields, see [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: *"Well, actually, the whole point is that I don't know how to make it so that the enter key will generate an event instead of having to click the button"* - Have you tried just pressing the [Enter] or [Space] key when the button is focused?  Have you tried just pressing the [Enter] key when the text field has focus?  See the linked tutorials in the previous comment (sorry if this sounds like we're giving you the run around, but the tutorials demonstrate these basic concepts)

Comment: I thought the only reason you used ActionListener was for button clicks on a button.

Comment: @James The reason for a `ActionListener` is to get notification that a "action" of some kind has occured.  It's up to the component to decide how that action is triggered, in the case of the button, either by the keyboard or mouse.  This creates a single, generalised callback which doesn't need to know "how" the event was generated, only that it was generated (appropriately for the component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a small class that implements KeyListener, but even though I implemented all methods, including keyPressed(), and gave them all code to run, nothing happens when I press the enter (return) key. Please help me with this problem, here is the class that I made implement KeyListener (the implemented methods are at the bottom):

Short answer, don't.  If you think you need a `KeyListener`, the likely hood is you don't.  A `KeyListener` is a low level API which you very rarely need to use, as there are generally better ways to achieve the same thing.

In your case, both the `JTextField` and `JButton` support event notification via the `ActionListener` interface.  In the case of the `JTextField`, this will notify you when the user presses the "action" key while field is focused and in the case of the `JButton`, when the user presses the "action", the buttons mnemonic key combination or presses the button with the mouse.

The `ActionListener` API is suppose to remove the complexity involved detecting this functionality and provide you with a simple call back through which you can perform the required action.  Let's face it, we don't really care "how" the component was activated, only that it was

Instead, get rid of the `KeyListener` and simply use something like...

```
ok.addActionListener(okListener);
defField.addActionListener(okListener);
```

This way, the user won't need to press the button, but can press the "action" key for the field and the same functionality will get executed.

See [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, it completely solved my problem. I tested the program and it works like a charm!